# Case Insensitive search from jTable stored values in Database SQlite (IDE: netbeans)

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, text, netbeans

I have created a database which is shown in `JTable`, I want to search a value from that `JTable` in case insensitive. code is below!

```
String sql = "select * from stock where Model=?" ;
       pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
       pst.setString(1, txt_search.getText());
       rs = pst.executeQuery();
       if(rs.next()){
            String add0 = rs.getString("Sr");
            txt_sr.setText(add0);
            String add1 = rs.getString("Code");
            txt_code.setText(add1);
            String add2 = rs.getString("Brand");
            txt_brand.setText(add2);
            String add3 = rs.getString("Type");
            txt_type.setText(add3);
            String add4 = rs.getString("Model");
            txt_model.setText(add4);
            String add5 = rs.getString("CodePrice");
            txt_cPrice.setText(add5);
            String add6 = rs.getString("RetailPrice");
            txt_rPrice.setText(add6);
            for(int i=0;i<table_stock.getRowCount();i++) {
            if(table_stock.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(Integer.valueOf(txt_sr.getText()))) {
            table_stock.setRowSelectionInterval(i, i);
            break;
            }
            }
        }
```

It searches properly but when the charaters are entered as these are stored like capital or lower case, I just want to enter in any case and get the search result no matter in which case it is stored!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used SQLlite but im going out on a limb here, can you convert both to lower case an compare?

```
String sql = "select * from stock where LOWER(Model)=?" ;
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, txt_search.getText().toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [COLLATE operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#collateop) to make case-insensitive comparisons:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE model = ? COLLATE NOCASE";
```

Alternatively, use the [LIKE operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) to do a case-insensitive search with wildcards; this is typcially used if you want to search for a prefix:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE model LIKE ?";
pst.setString(1, txt_search.getText() + '%');
```

Please note that to be able to use an index for case-insensitive searches, you have to declare it as such, too:

```sql
CREATE INDEX model_ci_idx ON stock(model COLLATE NOCASE);
```